# Display Variable value in Python using print Statement?

Tags: python

I have created a Python program that guesses the number programmer thinks in mind. Everything is working file but i don't know how to use guess in print statement in a way that print statement display number as well. I tried adding word "guess" but it is not working. I am C programmer and working with Python for the first time, so i am unable to figure it out.

```
hi = 100
lo = 0
guessed = False 

print ("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")

while not guessed:
    guess = (hi + lo)/2
print ("Is your secret number " + //Here i need to Display the guessed Number + "?")
user_inp = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too"
                     "low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly: ")

if user_inp == 'c':
    guessed = True
elif user_inp == 'h':
    hi = guess
elif user_inp == 'l':
    lo = guess
else:
    print ("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")

print ("Game over. Your secret number was: " + //Here i need to display final number saved in guess.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your print statement and let me know if it works.

```
str(guess)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just convert it to string.

```
print ("Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(guess))
```

You could also use string formatting.

```
print("Game over. Your secret number was {}".format(guess))
```

Or, since you come from a C background, old style string formatting.

```
print("Game over. Your secret number was %d." % guess)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has very nice string formatting, which comes in handy when you need to insert multiple variables:

```
message = "Game over after {n} guesses.  Your number was {g} (pooh... got it in {n} times)".format(g=guess, n=number)
print(message)
```